# Chamar Api no useEffect não funciona?

Tags: react-native

Estou com um probleminha aqui na chamada de uma API, código:

```
const [fullCurrency,setFullCurrency] = useState('');
function carregaMoedas(){
const res =  api.get('currencies?apiKey=do-not-use-this-key');
setFullCurrency(res.results);
  }
useEffect(()=>{
carregaMoedas();  
console.log(fullCurrency)
  },[]);
```

O trexo de codigo acima no console.log retorna

```
{"_U": 0, "_V": 3, "_W": {"_U": 0, "_V": 1, "_W": {"config": [Object], "data": [Object], "headers": [Object], "request": [XMLHttpRequest], "status": 200, "statusText": undefined}, "_X": null}, "_X": null}
```

Ja tentei de tudo aqui, más não consigo solucionar isto.
Obrigado pessoal!
Link completo da api https://free.currconv.com/api/v7/currencies?apiKey=do-not-use-this-key

Answer (score 0):

Faltou executar o [promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) para que a execução seja processada:

```
const [fullCurrency,setFullCurrency] = useState('');
function carregaMoedas(){
    api.get('currencies?apiKey=do-not-use-this-key')
       .then(result => setFullCurrency(result.results));
}
useEffect(() => {
    carregaMoedas();  
},[]);
useEffect(() => { 
    console.log(fullCurrency); 
}, [fullCurrency])
```

Exemplo minimo completo:

***Nota:*** foi utilizado [fetch](/questions/tagged/fetch) para requisição [ajax](/questions/tagged/ajax).

```js
function App() {
  const url = 'https://free.currconv.com/api/v7/currencies?apiKey=06370d8c7bb02f55780a';
  const [fullCurrency, setFullCurrency] = React.useState([]);
  function carregaMoedas(){
    fetch(url)
       .then(result => result.json())
       .then(result => {
           setFullCurrency(result.results)
       });
  }
  React.useEffect(() => {
      carregaMoedas();
  }, []);
  React.useEffect(() => {
    
  }, [fullCurrency]);
  return (
    <div>
      <h3>Moedas</h3> 
      {fullCurrency && fullCurrency.length === 0 && <div>Carregando ...</div>}
      {Object.entries(fullCurrency).map((item, index) => (
        <div>
          <h3>{item[0]}</h3>
          <div>
            {item[1].currencyName},
            {' '}
            {item[1].currencySymbol},
            {' '}
            {item[1].id}
          </div>
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  )
}

ReactDOM.render( <App/> , document.getElementById('root'));
```

```css
*, body {
   font-family:arial;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root">Carregando ...</div>
```

---

***Nota:*** foi utilizado [axios](/questions/tagged/axios) para requisição [ajax](/questions/tagged/ajax).

```js
function App() {
  const url = 'https://free.currconv.com/api/v7/currencies?apiKey=06370d8c7bb02f55780a';
  const [fullCurrency, setFullCurrency] = React.useState([]);
  function carregaMoedas(){
    axios.get(url)       
       .then(result => {        
           setFullCurrency(result.data.results)
       });
  }
  React.useEffect(() => {    
      carregaMoedas();
  }, []);
  React.useEffect(() => {
    
  }, [fullCurrency]);
  return (
    <div>
      <h3>Moedas</h3> 
      {fullCurrency && fullCurrency.length === 0 && <div>Carregando ...</div>}
      {Object.entries(fullCurrency).map((item, index) => (
        <div>
          <h3>{item[0]}</h3>
          <div>
            {item[1].currencyName},
            {' '}
            {item[1].currencySymbol},
            {' '}
            {item[1].id}
          </div>
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  )
}

ReactDOM.render( <App/> , document.getElementById('root'));
```

```css
*, body {
   font-family:arial;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>
<div id="root">Carregando ...</div>
```

Observe que existe diferenças nos dois exemplos tanto no `request` e `response` da chamada [ajax](/questions/tagged/ajax)